# VB.NET Load and call DLL dynamically - the arithmetic operation caused an overflow

Tags: vb.net, resources, .net-assembly, createinstance

Hey guys following problem.
I want to load a dll from embedded resources and inovke the entrypoint Sub Main().
But i get a exception when the desired Sub Main() from dll is triggerd. Sorry for my english. I hope you can explain the error and give me a solution.

Here is the DLL i want to load Sub Main():

```
Namespace MyApp

Public Class EntryPoint
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim FrmMain As New Form1
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(FrmMain)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Yeah it is correct that the dll loads a form on main()

And that is how i call it:

```
        Dim bytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(My.Resources.src2)
        Dim oType As System.Type
        Dim oAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
        Dim oObject As System.Object
        oAssembly = Assembly.Load(bytes)
        oType = oAssembly.GetType("MyApp.EntryPoint")
        oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
        oObject.Main()
```

The error that appears after 5 sec from loading sub main() is : "the arithmetic operation caused an overflow"

Please help me i am learning. Thank you very much.

Comment: The error most likely occurs in `Form1`. The message is an indication that you're performing a mathematical operation (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc.) which's result is either greater or less than what the data type you're using allows. For instance a normal `Integer` has a max limit of `2^31 - 1`, which is `2,147,483,647`. Check your mathematical operations in `Form1`.

Comment: Yep i expected that. But surprisingly i dont do mathematical operations.

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace of the exception? It will tell you 4exactly where it was thrown.

Comment: Error occurs here:
`bei Form1.kBHuuk.Hook()
   bei Form1.Form1_Load()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)`

Comment: Perhaps it could be that there is a problem with the arguements as if they are not correctyl given. But i really dont know.

Comment: Without seeing the code we can't help. According to the stack trace it occurs in `Form1.kBHuuk.Hook()`. Please update your question with the code calling `Hook()` and the code for the method itself.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the stack trace there.